# Randomize a #define at program start

Tags: c, random

I have an application which has a strict separation between user and the backend. The only way the user can interact with my backend is via one function. To specify what the user wants the first argument of this fucntion is the instruction the user wants the backend to execute (for example getData). This looks something like this

`backendcall(getData, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)`

The names of the services that my backend provides are saved in a .h file (called definitions.h). This file only contains #defines.

```c
#define getData 1
#define setData 2
...
```

This way it is easier for the user to make backend calls. 
For security reasons I would like to randomize the value of the #defines at the start.

I am aware that it is possible to call functions in a define like this
`#define var foo()`

My problem is that this does not work for me since I can not use a function to define the random value.
Even if I add an integer like this

`int asdfqweryxcv = 20;`

I get an error message on compilation that this value has multiple definitions. I can change the name to whatever I want the result is always the same.

The Error message looks like this:

```
../../lib.a(userfile1.c.o):/home/../../../definitions.h:8: multiple definition of `asdfqweryxcv'
CMakeFiles/mult.c.o:/home/../../../definitions.h:8: first defined here

../../lib.a(userfile2.c.o):/home/../../../definitions.h:8: multiple definition of `asdfqweryxcv'
CMakeFiles/mult.c.o:/home/../../../definitions.h:8: first defined here

...
```

I would like to randomize these defines and have a unique number for every define.

Comment: How do you expect randomised values to increase security? The values still need to be exposed to the user of your library anyway.

Comment: If you randomize it every time you compile, how will the values in the client match what is deployed on the backend?

Comment: Your multiple definitions issue has nothing to do with anything you've decribed. Just define the function as `inline`.

Comment: *This way the user it is easier for the user.* - What?

Comment: Please elaborate on the "for security reasons" bit. What are those reasons? What behavior are you trying to prevent? Security doesn't make sense in a vacuum, you have to have some attack vector in mind.

Comment: Also, if your code is split into a library, or even just 2 .c files, (one for user one for backend) how will the two modules get the same index? You could make it an argument to make, but then what about partial compilation, the whole point of make?

Comment: Ignoring the whole randomization aspect (which seems like either a misunderstanding of the question or something that would never work anyway), a possible answer to "have a unique number for every define" is to use an `enum` instead of `#define`, since every case gets a number that is one greater than the previous.

Comment: @Quentin thank you for this information now I understand why I am having the problem with multiple definitions.

Comment: I think you just want enum. `enum backendcall_type_e { getData, setData, .... };`

Comment: @KonradRudolph I thought that if I randomize the values of the backend calls it would be harder for a user to write malicious that can exploit my system by just using the exact same value every time. This way he would have to use the defined names that I gave the user. Am i wrong with this assumption?  Thank you very much for your input.

Comment: "would be harder for a user to write malicious ..." --> yes.  Would is be sufficiently harder - perhaps not.  At a minimum, `asdfqweryxcv` should be 64 bit. As for me, I'd like to see the overall goal details more.

Comment: @Mark If the attacker has access to the compiled binary, then there is no difference (the names only exist in the source code anyway). Or if they can observe calls made by an actual client, they can just use those. If neither, then how would they know to make that format of call anyway? (Also, hopefully your system has other measures of security for making a call than being able to guess its number.) And the question remains: since the names don't exist in the call (you are only sending numbers), how do you sync the backend and client so that both understand what each number means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Randomize a #define at program start

Is not possible. Pre-processor macros are expanded at pre-processing time which happens before compilation which happens before program start.

What you need is a variable. Sure, you can define a macro to expand to the variable name, but that has little advantage to using the variable directly.

> I get an error message on compilation that this value has multiple definitions.

More accurately, the error message is on linking, which is after compilation.

You must declare the variable `extern` in the header. Then in exactly one translation unit, define the variable (without `extern`). Be careful to not attempt to use the value before you've initialised it or you'll get zero instead of the random value.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer to all my questions. This has helped me a lot.